# Отметить Checkbox при условии (чистый js)

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью чистого JS отметить `checkbox` с `id="dva"` , если отмечен `checkbox` с `id="odin"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (odin.checked) {
     dva.checked = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

как-то так :

```js
document.getElementById('dva').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById('odin').checked = !document.getElementById('dva').checked;
});

document.getElementById('odin').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById('dva').checked = !document.getElementById('odin').checked;
});
```

```html
<label for="odin">Odin</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="odin" />
<br />
<label for="dva">Dva</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="dva" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```js
var chckbx = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

Array.from(chckbx).forEach(function (chck) {
  chck.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    Array.from(chckbx).forEach(function (chck) {
      chck.checked = false;
    });
    
    e.target.checked = true;
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="odin">
<label for="odin">Odin</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="dva">
<label for="dva">Dva</label>
```